# Swing- GridbagLayout - problem

Tags: java, swing, grid, gridbaglayout

I am adding number of small panels in Frame using GridBagLayout as
Show and Hidden list.

When adding to show list, pack happens and panel displayed immediately

but when adding to hidden list, pack happens and panel still display until a refresh done.

panel1 panel2

panel1 panel2  [hiding panel2 - is not done immediately]

panel1

panel1 panel2 [showing panel2 - happens immediately]

can anyone help with exact code that i should use..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Everybody should read this: Totally Gridbag http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/

Comment: Atleast provide a snippet to get to know on what is being done..

Comment: Gridbag totally. MigLayout all the way.

Answer (score 4):

After adding call revalidate(); and repaint();

Comment: eeerrrgghhhttt that my song +1

Comment: revalidate() method for frame??

Comment: For the container. E.g. for panel where you add/remove components.

Comment: [revalidate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29)
[repaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29)